# Using a Pandas DataFrame as Lookup

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have 2 pandas DataFrames, this one:

```
item    inStock     description  
Apples    10        a juicy treat
Oranges   34        mediocre at best
Bananas   21        can be used as phone prop
<...many other fruits...>
Kiwi       0        too fuzzy
```

and a lookup table with only a subset of the items above:

```
item     Price
Apples   1.99
Oranges  6.99
```

I would like to scan through the first table and fill in a price column for the DataFrame when the fruit in the first DataFrame matches the fruit in the second:

```
item    inStock     description                   Price
Apples    10        a juicy treat                 1.99
Oranges   34        mediocre at best              6.99
Bananas   21        can be used as phone prop
<...many other fruits...>
Kiwi       0        too fuzzy
```

I've looked at examples with the built-in lookup function, as well as using a where-in type function but I cannot seem to get the syntax to work.  Can someone help me out?

Comment: You could just do `lhs.merge(rhs, on='item', how='left)` this will match on item and add the corresponding value, where there is no match `NaN` will appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df_item= pd.read_csv('Item.txt')
df_price= pd.read_csv('Price.txt')

df_final=pd.merge(df_item,df_price ,on='item',how='left' )
print df_final
```

output

```
      item  inStock                description  Price
0   Apples       10              a juicy treat   1.99
1  Oranges       34           mediocre at best   6.99
2  Bananas       21  can be used as phone prop    NaN
3     Kiwi        0                  too fuzzy    NaN
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.